# Textview with Suggestions List in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I am trying to implement a textView in which when user starts typing(Let's say names) it would show up the suggestions and when they click them it gets added to the textView than user presses comma and again the same functionality for another name....

And at the end the text in the textView should look like this...

Aron,Maria,Alex,Cassie

Can any one suggest me How can I achieve this?
(Its somewhat similar to adding the "Tags" while posting this question!!!)

Thanks.

Comment: Try this :- https://github.com/Datt1994/DPTagDetectionTextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a NSTokenField replacement there is some libraries here :

[tokenField libraries](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=token)

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/copeoplepickerviewcontroller...this control is somewhat useful but its lacking the search functionality...It does not search any content while typing...

Comment: If you try it in iphone simulator the method - (void)tokenField:(COTokenField *)tokenField updateAddressBookSearchResults:(NSArray *)records always return the same values.

Comment: Yes thats what I am talking about...I need suggestions not the same values each time

Comment: For that you need to subclass COPeoplePickerViewController and establish your own datasource. I try it on my iphone and COPeoplePickerViewController display my adresseBook values not always the same

Answer (score 1):

Following link may help you: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Follow the same flow. To get autocomplete suggestions after comma modify the delegate method as found below.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
    replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

  NSString *names = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
  NSArray* arr = [names componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
  NSString *subString = [arr lastObject];
  substring = [substring 
    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
  return YES;
}
```

Provide a NSMutableArray named 'allNames' which contains all the names you want to display in the suggestion list and use it as the following:

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {
  [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
  for(NSString *curString in allNames) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
      [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
  }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

When the user clicks the suggestions display the name by appending with previously entered names.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // set the textField.text by appending this name to already entered names

}
```

Comment: Thanks Siva for your suggestions but to implement your suggestion I have to take one textfield to add names and one textView to display the names...and I have already done this..

Comment: This can be done in single textView.What do you mean by 'add names'. As i understood, user will enter name in the given textView. Delegate method and searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring method will take care of displaying the suggestion list. Once selecting the name from the list(tableView) you need to set it for textField.text. Assign the name in NSString. If user enter comma and enters another name, the above process will repeat. Once user select from list you need to append ',secondName' to the previous string and set as textField.text(the same textView)

Comment: Its giving following error while adding a comma..[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything like this in mobile app. You can look for libraries. But if you want to make it yourself I would advice you to use invisible tableView. When user starts typing name you should fetchData and show in tableView under textView. It's not hard.

Comment: :Thanks for your advice but I don't have enough time to make it myself....rather than you can suggest me an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy way I can think of to achieve this functionality would be to add an input accessory view to your keyboard, which will offer suggestions.

You wouldn't have to tamper with the TextField itself, nor would you need to incorporate the suggestions into the remainder of your apps layout.

The accessory view could, for example, be given a reference to the textfield and listen to input by:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChanged) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:textFieldWithSuggestions];
```

It would feature a method -(void)textChanged; in which you would have the opportunity to split the existing text into components, using comma or whatever symbol as a separator, and then use the last text fragment to perform your search for possible completions.

It may present these suggestions as a row of buttons for example (maybe even in a side-scrolling scrollview to allow for many suggestions) and if one gets pushed, update the textfields text by replacing the last text segment with the completed string.

To keep track of which button stands for which suggestion, just give them tags according to the indices of your search results. This way, you'll need only one method as a target for the buttons, too.

Comment: I understood what you are saying but I have no clue about how can I implement this thing??

Answer (score -1):

If you want to some library code then you can go for this
https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField which will help you

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this library its just an AutocompleteTextField