# Add subview to a custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, addsubview

I have a UITextField that I want to create a custom class on. So I created a file with a subclass of `UITextField`. Next, in the custom class, I want to implement a `tableView`. Kind of like a auto-complete `textField`.

I started creating it, and added the `tableView` like this:

```
[self addSubview:self.tableView];
```

When I run the app, the `tableView` is in the `textField`, so I can only see part of the `tableView`. How can I add it as a `subview` so I can see the full `tableView`?

Comment: I guess you want to customize UITableView actually, because I can't see that you are using a customized UITextField. And try to explain your requirement clearly in question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that UITextField is not the kind of class that handles subclassing very well. I would suggest you to use composition over subclassing.
Create your own UIView subclass with UITexField and UITableView as subviews.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686379/textview-with-suggestions-list-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for
https://github.com/gaurvw/MPGTextField

This uitextfield subclass does what you want - it's builed for 'search' feature.
If you still want to use your own, 
add tableview not to uitextfield itself, but like

```
[[self superview] addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];
```

**EDIT:**

you can set frame as:

```
 CGRect frameForPresentation = [self frame];
 frameForPresentation.origin.y += self.frame.size.height;
 frameForPresentation.size.height = 200;
 [tableViewController.tableView setFrame:frameForPresentation];
```

The way to add subview to uitextfield is to overload layoutSubviews method and init your tableview there:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{ 
[super layoutSubviews]; 
if (!self.tableview.superview) 
{ 
[self setupView]; 
} 
}
```

Comment: I tried that without a tableViewController, just a tableView. When I run the app, I don't see any tableViews

Comment: how do you set frame of your tableview?

Comment: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300)

Comment: try to use uitextfield frame as basic frame for your tableview, as i mention on my edit

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the frame, because i do see part of it when I do self addSubiew.

Comment: Also, like @liushuaikobe said, I inserted self.clipsToBounds = NO; and I see the whole thing, but I just can't select the cells under the textField

Comment: heh, the problem is that tableview will always cut by textfield frame. add it to [self superview] addSubview:  with correct frame. Does this work?

Comment: I tried that, and insertSubview: aboveView, and both didn't show any tableView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81366/discussion-between-doro-and-jessica).

Answer (score 0):

This will add the `tableView` as the subView of the `textField`.

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), YOUR_TABLE_HEIGHT);
[self addSubview:self.tableView];
self.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

However, a better way is to make the `tableView` as the `textField`'s superView's subView, that is, the `textField` and the `tableView` should be siblings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! When I do `self.clipsToBounds = NO;` then it shows the tableView as it should, but the cells under the textField aren't clickable.

Comment: @Jessica Then why not try a better way? make the `textField` and the `tableView` siblings.

Comment: What do you mean siblings!! Sorry... I'm a newbie

Comment: @Jessica Add the `tableView` to the `textFiled`'s superView's subView rather than the `textFiled`'s subView.

Comment: When I do [`self.superview addSubview:self.tableView]`, I don't see the tableView

Comment: @Jessica Because the frame of the `tableView` is not correct. Try to set the frame of the `tableView` to `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, 300);` Then, `[self.superView addSubview:self.tableView]`

Comment: I don't think the tableViews frame isn't the problem, because when self.clipsToBounds is NO, I see it, but can't select it